# How to bundle a string correctly to other Activity in Android?

Tags: android

The integers pass successfully but string is failed. What's the problem?

Result:
http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/2079/app2v.jpg

Comment: Have you called getText() on the Editfield prior to adding to extra?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the EditText.toString() but as Pentium10 said, you have to call getText()